# Increase 100 File Upload Limit

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, file-upload

How can I increase the 100 file upload limit in drag & drop upload in SharePoint 2013?

I would also like to know if this limit is applicable to permissions levels -> i.e. can a user with Site Owner permission be configured to upload a great er number of files than 100?